# Nested components in re-frame not updating

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I'm building a single-page app using re-frame. Each "page" of the app calls a component `base-page` then supplies its page-specific children...

```
(defn base-page [& children]
  (into [:div
         ; banner goes here
        ] children))

(register-sub :count
  (fn [db _] (reaction (:count @db))))

(register-handler :inc
  (fn [db _] (update db :count inc)))

(defn test-page []
  (let [count (subscribe [:count])]
    (fn []
      [base-page 
       [:h2 "Test Page"]
       [:p (str "Count: " @count)]])))
```

This renders the page correctly with the initial value for `:count`, and when I run `(dispatch [:inc])` the page updates correctly.

Now I'd like `base-page` to be a form-2 component so it can have it's own subscriptions...

```
(defn base-page [& children]
  (let [user (subscribe [:current-user])]
    (fn []
    (into [:div
           ; banner goes here, including @user
          ] children))
```

However, when I do this, the count on `test-page` no longer updates when I run `(dispatch [:inc])`. I find this surprising, because I thought Reagent packages form-1 and form-2 components into form-3 components behind the scenes.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, is there a better way to implement my base page/concrete page model?

Comment: Isn't it a rule in the re-frame documentation that for form-2 components the outer function and the inner function must have the same arguments?

Comment: I must have read that rule 10 times and it didn't click that it was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it a rule in the re-frame Reagent documentation (*) that for Form-2 components the outer function and the inner function must have the same arguments?

Check out the second 'rookie mistake' on [this page](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components)

(*) re-frame depends on Reagent. The documentation about Form-1/2/3 components applies equally to using Reagent on its own or from one of the other frameworks/libraries that sit on top of Reagent.

Answer (score 3):

As Chris Murphy pointed out, the problem was that I wasn't passing the outer arguments to my inner function. This definition of `base-page` works fine:

```
(defn base-page [& children]
  (let [user (subscribe [:current-user])]
    (fn [& children]
    (into [:div
           ; banner goes here, including @user
          ] children))
```